# How to keep Joomla (1.5) from rewriting my header tags

Tags: html, joomla

In a [Jumi](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/1023/details) script, I'm generating the following HTML:

```
<h3>Header title</h3>
```

When I view the page, Firebug indicates that the element has turned into this:

```
<h3>
    <a _moz-rs-heading="" name="header-title">Header title</a>
</h3>
```

This does not appear in the page source, so it has been changed dynamically somehow.  However, even if JavaScript is disabled, this will happen.

So why would I want to suppress this useful feature?  Well, I reload the page content with AJAX every ten seconds or so.  Content introduced by `jQuery('#my_container').html(...)` does not have its header tags rewritten.  Thus, after ten seconds, the header tags will turn from blue to black.

My questions are:

- What part of the Joomla source code is responsible for these header tag rewrites?
- How can I create header tags that opt out of such rewrites?

Answer (score 0):

Joomla builds header in this file: 
/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php

You can skip Joomla headers by removing following line from your template's index.php file:

```
<jdoc:include type="head" />
```